# Get the domain part of an URL string?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, ios4

I have an NSString with an URL, in this way:

```
http://someurl.com/something
```

How would I get `someurl.com` only?
I've already tried `substringToIndex` with no luck :(

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 100, accepted):

**Objective-C**

```
NSString* urlString = @"http://someurl.com/something";
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSString* domain = [url host];
```

**Swift 2**

```
var urlString = "http://someurl.com/something"
var url = NSURL(string: urlString)
var domain = url?.host
```

**Swift 3+**

```
var urlString = "http://someurl.com/something"
var url = URL(string: urlString)
var domain = url?.host
```

Comment: Almost but it leaves extra `www.` at the beginning

Comment: Yes, because that's part of the host name.

Comment: You are mistaken. For example, read the following: http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/D/domain_name.html   In short words: `http://www.pcwebopedia.com/index.html` -> `pcwebopedia.com`

Comment: Wikipedia says "Any name registered in the DNS is a domain name."

Comment: Ok. But the idea of wiki is Everyone can write Everything he wants at any time and without additional efforts and consequences. So I don't consider its data.

Comment: @StephenDarlington You're right that it's part of the host name, but is there a correct way to strip the "www."? Should I just use `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 11):

Use

```
[[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://someurl.com/something"] host]
```

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 4.2**

I wrote extension for URL to take SLD. Seems, there is n

```
extension URL {
    /// second-level domain [SLD]
    ///
    /// i.e. `msk.ru, spb.ru`
    var SLD: String? {
        return host?.components(separatedBy: ".").suffix(2).joined(separator: ".")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 5**

Extension to string, that gives you the domain name, while also removing "www."

```
extension String {
func StripURLMakeAttractive(_ url: String) -> String {
        
    let url = URL(string: url)
    guard let domain = url?.host else {return "error"}
    var modifiedDomain: String = ""
    
    var checkWWW: String = ""
    let checkIndexes = [0,1,2,3]

    for (index,char) in domain.enumerated() {
        if checkIndexes.contains(index){
            checkWWW.append(char)
        }
        if index > 3 && checkWWW.lowercased() == "www."  {
            modifiedDomain.append(char)
        }
    }
    
    if checkWWW.lowercased() == "www."{
        return modifiedDomain
    }
    else {
        return domain
    }
    
}
```

}

Comment: Works! I modified it to not accept any arguments and use self instead of the url param as I am calling this extension method using my URLString.

Answer (score 2):

### Swift 5.5

```
extension String {
    var onlyHost: String? {
        let url = URL(string: self)
        return url?.host
    }
}
```

Comment: Why an Extension to String? It doesnt't even reference `self`. Maybe you meant to write `func getHost() -> String?` without the extra String argument?

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the [host()](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html) method of the [NSURL](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4**

And if you are using **Custom url schemes** say for deeplinking, for eg:

```
myapp:homescreen
```

(and  don't have the "forward slashes with host name" (//www.bbc)), one solution that worked for me to extract "homescreen" is by `using the index` method below and then `pattern matching` to scrape everything after `":"`

```
let index = absoluteString.index(absoluteString.startIndex, offsetBy: 5)
String(absoluteString[index...])
```

`url.host` or `absoluteURL.host` is **`nil`** in this scenario