# How to get top level domain name of URL in swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsurl

My requirement is to get domain name of URL by filtering out it's subdomain name.

i can get host name by using code as below

```
if let url = URL(string: "https://blog.abc.in/")  {
    if let hostName = url.host  {
         print("host name = \(hostName)") // output is: blog.mobilock.in
    }
 }
```

so here in URL *blog* is a subdomain and *abc* is a domain name, I wish to know/print only *abc* by excluding its subdomain parts.

In android, there is a class [InternetDomainName](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/20.0/api/docs/com/google/common/net/InternetDomainName.html) which return domain name, the similar solution I am looking for iOS

I tried several answers and it's not duplicate of any or some of them is not working or that is a workaround.

[Get the domain part of an URL string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6162522/3145189)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So finally i found better and standard approach for this issue -

Mozilla volunteers maintain Public Suffix List and [there](https://publicsuffix.org/learn/) you can find list of library for respective language.
so in list [Swift library](https://github.com/Dashlane/SwiftDomainParser) is also present. 
At the time of writing this answer [Swift library](https://github.com/Dashlane/SwiftDomainParser) don't have provison of adding it through CocoPods so you have to add downloaded project directly into your project. Code to get TLD name assuming [Swift library](https://github.com/Dashlane/SwiftDomainParser) is added into your project.

```
import DomainParser

static func getTLD(withSiteURL:String) -> String? {
        do{
            let domainParse = try DomainParser()
            if let publicSuffixName = domainParse.parse(host: withSiteURL)?.publicSuffix {
                if let domainName = domainParse.parse(host: withSiteURL)?.domain {

                    let tldName = domainName.replacingOccurrences(of: publicSuffixName, with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: "")
                    print("top level name = \(tldName)")
                    return tldName
                }
            }
        }catch{
        }
        return nil
    }
```

Add Domain parser library as sub-project of your project, as pod of this library is not available yet

Answer (score 2):

It is just a workaround but works perfectly:

```
    if let url = URL(string: "https://x.y.z.a.b.blog.mobilock.in/")  {
        if let hostName = url.host  {
            print("host name = \(hostName)") // output is: x.y.z.a.b.blog.mobilock.in

            let subStrings = hostName.components(separatedBy: ".")
            var domainName = ""
            let count = subStrings.count
            if count > 2 {
                domainName = subStrings[count - 2] + "." + subStrings[count - 1]
            } else if count == 2 {
                domainName = hostName
            }
            print(domainName)
        }
    }
```

Let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: thanks priyal, but is this solution can handle  foo.co.uk , here at the end of url there is 2 public suffix one is .co and second is .uk

Answer (score 2):

There is no simple way, regardless of language. See [How to extract top-level domain name (TLD) from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066933/how-to-extract-top-level-domain-name-tld-from-url) for some good discussion of the difficulties involved.

Answer (score 0):

To fetch the root domain of a URL, you can use the following `URL` extension:

```
extension URL {
    var rootDomain: String? {
        guard let hostName = self.host else { return nil }
        let components = hostName.components(separatedBy: ".")
        if components.count > 2 {
            return components.suffix(2).joined(separator: ".")
        } else {
            return hostName
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: see my comment at @priyal answer, a domain name  is not just having patterns it is  database of patterns, which get updated regularly

Comment: @sheshnath you're right. Top level domains can have different patterns like `co.uk`