# How to fetch a particular part of a string from the same string in Swift?

Tags: swift, string

I want to fetch a part of string from a string. E.g. I have a string say `sampleStringUrl` which holds "http://some.something.net/update/user". So, I want to get only "some.something.net" from `sampleStringUrl`.

Comment: "I want to" is not a good question, specially when the question shows no attempt from OP to solve the issue

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Okay, I'll keep that in mind from next time.

Answer (score 1):

Like that you want to get Host URL.

```
var urlString = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162522/get-the-domain-part-of-an-url-string"
var url = URL(string: urlString)
var domain = url?.host
print(domain!) //stackoverflow.com
```